# integer ranges using sizeof operator

Tags: c, sizeof

Consider this:

```
1. printf(“%d”, sizeof(32767));
2. printf(“%d”, sizeof(-32767));
3. printf(“%d”, sizeof(-32768));
```

1 and 2 yielded the result as 2 while the third statement yielded a 4. but the range of `int` is from -32768 to 32767. why is there a difference in third statement alone? can anyone explain this please?

in my compiler size of `int` is 2.

Comment: It shouldn't. Post the whole program. `sizeof` does not evaluate its arguments -- only looks at the type.

Comment: [Works as expected on gcc](http://ideone.com/xUjqe)

Comment: @Als you are not at the range boundary with 32768 and 32b representation. We must use 2147483648. And it still works as expected: http://ideone.com/Vqi96

Comment: @puller: True, but the point is that the range shouldn't matter, The arguments to `sizeof` are not evaluated only the type matters.

Answer (score 6):

The value `-32768` is not seen as a single item by the language, it is composed of two parts - a sign and a value.

The value `32768` cannot be an `int` when the upper limit is 32767. So it is determined to be a larger type, like `long`. Only after that is the sign applied.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler reads this as `-` applied to the constant 32768. As 32768 is outside the range of an `int` (in this particular compiler) it will be promoted to a `long`.

In fact, many implementation of standard headers define, say, `INT_MIN` as something like `(-32767-1)` to avoid this problem.

Comment: Is there any proof for this statement? I failed to find a version of "limits.h" that does this. Some do things like `#define INT_MIN (-INT_MAX - 1)` but I'd assume this is to make maintenance easier (so that you can change `INT_MAX` to suit a different architecture without also needing to change `INT_MIN`).

Answer (score 1):

Integer constants are `int` by default, but are promoted to the smallest size that is large enough to hold them (e.g. `long`) when necessary (when they don't fit in an `int`).

If an `int` is 16-bits, then (for 2's complement) the maximum theoretical range is from -32768 to +32767. However, in practice this breaks things like `abs()` as it's impossible (for 16-bit) to return a valid value for `abs(-32768)`. Compilers may avoid the problem by setting `INT_MIN` to -32767 instead; so that `abs()` behaves correctly for all valid values of `int` and doesn't unexpectedly blow up in your face (e.g. `abs(-32768) = -32768`).

The end result of this would be that the integer constant -32768 which could theoretically fit in an 16-bit `int` may be promoted to `long` because it is less than `INT_MIN`.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It has nothing to do with -32768 fitting or not fitting in int, because the integer literal in the source is NOT -32768. It's 32768. The - sign is an operator applied to it. And 32768 can never fit in a 16bit signed int.

Comment: Wrong. The source clearly shows `sizeof(-32768)` where the integer literal is obviously `-32768`. The minus sign is not a separate negation operator but is part of the integer literal. In addition the source does not say `sizeof(-(32768) )`. In a similar way, floating point literals aren't composed of integers, "decimal operators" and "exponent operators"; and "0x" is not a separate "convert hex string to integer" operator. Any compiler that is too buggy to parse negative integer literals correctly (that treat `-32768` as a positive integer with a negation operator) is a buggy piece of trash.

Comment: @Brendan You will find the grammar for integer constants in section 6.4.4.1 "Integer constants" of the C99 standard. Note how the hexadecimal prefix is part of the grammar, but the minus sign is not.

Comment: @Brendan: Well then all conformant C compilers are "buggy pieces of trash". Next time try reading the standard rather than making stuff up.